# TailwindCSS @layer components being dropped when using documentation --minify command

Tags: css, tailwind-css, bundling-and-minification

Following the TailwindCSS documentation, i am trying to minify my final stylesheet to optimise it for production. However i am losing custom styles added via `@layer components {}` when minifying.

I have a simple .css file for my Tailwind set up containing the following code:

```
@layer components {
    .button {
        @apply text-white bg-neutral-900 inline-flex text-sm font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-3xl md:px-9 md:py-2 border-2 border-neutral-900 transition-all;
    }
}
```

When i compile (un-minified), i can use the `.button` selector on elements and this pulls through my styles as expected.

However, when i run `npx tailwindcss -o ./dist/styles/tailwind.css --minify`, the `.button` selector is no longer within my minified stylesheet.

Where am i going wrong here? I have tried adding the `.button` selector to my `tailwind.config.js` safelist, as well as adding my `./src/styles/tailwind.css` (as `"./src/styles/*.css`) to my `content` array within my config file. Neither of these seem to resolve my issue.